# How do I get the "td" in a table element with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I need to get the "td" element of a table.  I do not have the ability to add a mouseover or onclick event to the "td" element, so I need to add them with JQUERY.

I need JQUERY to add the mouseover and onclick event to the all "td" elements in the table.

Thats what I need, maybe someone can help me out?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $("table#mytable td").mouseover(function() {
        //The onmouseover code
    }).click(function() {
        //The onclick code
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Work off of the following code to get you started.  It should do just what you need.

```
$("td").hover(function(){
   $(this).css("background","#0000ff");
},
function(){
  $(this).css("background","#ffffff");
});
```

You can use [this as a reference, which is where I pulled that code](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-jquery2/).